# How to use Menhir error messages generation via OCamlbuild?

Tags: makefile, ocaml, ocamlbuild, menhir

I am using the `--compile-errors` functionality of `menhir` and I'm quite happy with it. I'm also using `ocamlbuild` to manage the compilation of my project. Since the project is quite basic, the build infrastructure has remained trivial so far.

I have a single `_tags` file and a simple `Makefile` at the root of the project. I don't have a `myocamlbuild.ml` file yet. The `_tags` file contains just one line:

```
<src/*>: package(ppx_deriving.std)
```

The relevant part of the Makefile is

```
all: src/ParsingErrors.ml
    ocamlbuild $(OPTIONS) src/Main.native

src/ParsingErrors.ml: src/Handcrafted.messages src/Parser.mly
    menhir --compile-errors src/Handcrafted.messages src/Parser.mly > src/ParsingErrors.ml

OPTIONS = -j 4 -use-menhir -use-ocamlfind -yaccflag --table -pkgs menhirLib,str,unix
```

OCamlbuild and Menhir are usually well integrated, but `--compile-errors` seems to be a fairly new functionality. My setup is not ideal because I dislike having an automatically generated file, `src/ParsingErrors.ml`, in my source directory instead of the build directory. What would be the best way to explain to OCamlbuild that I want Menhir to build this error messages file? Changing the naming convention of my files (into `src/Parser.messages` and `src/Parser.ml`, for example) does not bother me if it simplifies things.

NB: although I have `myocamlbuild.ml` files in other projects, I copied them from online sources. I find them hard to decipher and I don't really understand how to write these things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best place to look for an answer to this question is in Menhir's distribution, since Menhir uses "menhir --compile-errors" and ocamlbuild in its own compilation process.

The file to look for is `src/myocamlbuild.ml` in the [source tarball](http://gallium.inria.fr/~fpottier/menhir/menhir-20161115.tar.gz).

Here is a relevant excerpt:

```
(* This rule generates an .ml file [target] from an .mly file [grammar] and a
   .messages file [messages]. *)

(* If the name of a witness file is passed, it is made an additional
   dependency. This triggers a separate rule (see below) which performs a
   completeness check, that is, which checks that the .messages file lists
   every possible syntax error. *)

let compile_errors grammar messages (witness : string list) target =
  rule
    "menhir/compile_errors"
    ~prod:target
    ~deps:([ grammar; messages ] @ witness)
    (fun env _ ->
      let grammar = env grammar in
      let tags = tags_of_pathname grammar ++ "ocaml" ++ "menhir" in
      Cmd(S[
        !Options.ocamlyacc; (* menhir *)
        T tags;
        P grammar;
        A "--compile-errors"; P (env messages);
        Sh ">"; Px (env target);
      ]))

(* A generic version of the above rule, with uniform naming. *)

let generic_compile_errors (check_completeness : bool) =
  compile_errors
    (* sources: *)
    "%.mly" "%Messages.messages"
    (* if present, this dependency forces a completeness check: *)
    (if check_completeness then [ "%Messages.witness" ] else [])
    (* target: *)
    "%Messages.ml"
```

I would be happy to discuss with the ocamlbuild maintainers whether some parts of Menhir's myocamlbuild.ml could be moved into ocamlbuild's standard set of rules. (Hi Gabriel!)

Comment: This almost works for me, except that `!Options.ocamlyacc` is the empty string, so I had to replace it with `A "menhir"`. Would you have a guess why?

Answer (score 2):

The feature is indeed not supported in current ocamlbuild versions. To add it in your `myocamlbuild.ml` plugin, you would have to define a new build rule. If you are scared by what is inside `myocamlbuild.ml`, you may be interested in the new [ocamlbuild manual](https://github.com/ocaml/ocamlbuild/blob/master/manual/manual.adoc), in particular [its section on plugins](https://github.com/ocaml/ocamlbuild/blob/master/manual/manual.adoc#Sec_Plugins).

I just opened an [issue report #121](https://github.com/ocaml/ocamlbuild/issues/121) on the ocamlbuild repository to track this missing feature. Are you interested in learning enough about ocamlbuild to write a proper rule for this and contribute it to the next ocamlbuild version? If yes, feel free to the github issue and start asking questions about how to implement it, I would be glad to help. If not, I'll try to implement it myself when I have some time.

In the meantime, note that it's much easier to define a one-shot rule for specific files than a generic rule. If you are ready to hardcode the sourcefiles you use, you could have something that would look very similar to the Makefile rule. I don't have the time today to write and check this rule, but I'll try to come back tomorrow if someone else hasn't done it in between.